# How to Optimize this Query

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I'm learning MS SQL Server 2008 R2 so please excuse my ignorance.
This query takes 3 sec and I would like to do it in less than 1 sec.
the query is only for testing purposes, in reality I would join on different fields.

```
select * from
(
select row_number() over(order by t1.id) as n, t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, t3.id as id3, t4.id as id4, t5.id as id5
from dbo.Context t1
inner join dbo.Context t2 on t1.id = t2.test
inner join dbo.Context t3 on t2.id = t3.test
inner join dbo.Context t4 on t3.id = t4.test
inner join dbo.Context t5 on t4.id = t5.test
) as t
where t.n between 950000 and 950009;
```

I'm afraid this will be worse by the time I have several billion records in this table.

Do I need to enable multi-threading from configuration or something?

Comment: Will probably help if you index the id columns.

Comment: please tell us what you want to achieve. We will be able to help you way better that way.

Comment: @JamesLove: primary keys are not indexed by default ?

Comment: @Femaref: I have nested contexts that I want to query. ctx1.outterCtx = ctx2.id means ctx1 is nested into ctx2. In my test query I just want to test the performance of many joins since I'll have to query many contexts one nested into the other

Comment: @geeko: You say "in reality I would join on different fields" which means any optimisation of the query you have shown will not necessarily work for your *real* query. Why not show the query you actually want optimised?

Comment: @Tony: sorry, I really meant different field names but everything else is the same (id and test are of type INT and id is indexed by default because it is primary key)

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to optimize the `paging` portion of such a query, the part that is

```
t.n between 950000 and 950009
```

Which is really

```
{ ROW_NUMBER } between 950000 and 950009
```

Without fully materializing the INNER JOINs, there is no way to accurately row-number the result.  This is unlike a single table with Row_Number - the Query Optimizer can sometimes just count the index keys and go to a direct range.

The only thing you can do is ensure that the JOIN conditions are all fully indexed and have the indexes INCLUDE the columns that will be selected (so they become COVERING INDEXes).  There is no point showing specifics since those are not your real columns.

> Do I need to enable multi-threading from configuration or something?

By default, parallelism is [already] turned on so such a query will very likely gather the data in multiple streams.

Comment: No way to improve this query JOINS other than indexing the JOIN fields ? If NOT, how about NoSQL databases; would they be any better ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating the inner query as an indexed view and then running your paging off of that. Since an indexed view actually has a real index on it the same optimization tricks that work on tables can be used.

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx) for more information on indexed views including the limitations.